# Derivative of p- normalized vector

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I have an equation that I'm slightly uncertain as to how to take the derivative of a piece of it. If anyone can confirm that would be appreciated!

$y = c\|w\|_2^2$

$dy/dw = c \ \frac{d}{dw}{(\|w\|_2^2)}$

since:
$\|w\|_2^2 = \left(\sqrt{w_1^2...+w_p^2}\right)^2 = w_1^2...+w_p^2$

then 
$d/dw{(\|{w}\|_2^2)}=2(w_1+...+w_p)$

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're dealing with vectors here, so I would say that you should be taking gradients.

$y = c \|\mathbf{w}\|^2_2 = c \mathbf{w^Tw}$

$\Rightarrow\nabla_w y = 2 c \mathbf{w}$

$\Rightarrow \nabla_w y = 2{c\mathbf{w}}$

Comment: I edited the original equation. Please let me know if that alters this

Comment: @SebastianŁącki Updated.

Comment: What about the p-norm? Do we not have to consider that at all?

Comment: @SebastianŁącki It's a 2-norm. The square of a 2-norm for $w$ is $w^Tw$.